# What Package is Responsible for Volume Control?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 17.10

I'm trying to troubleshoot another problem that I'm having. I need to know what package is responsible for the behavior of Volume Up/Volume Down in Kubuntu 17.xx so I can try to restore this functionality. I'm using an HP laptop.

Comment: I believe it is KMix . https://multimedia.kde.org/

Comment: @Panther Hmm, this restored volume control, but it's not the same graphic as when Kubuntu is installed by default. I guess I shouldn't be so picky :D Thanks!

Comment: `pavucontrol` is likely the one you want

Comment: @ravery `pavucontrol` is a GUI application though. It didn't restore the volume buttons on my machine. I tried that first :D

Comment: ah, I misunderstood the level of volume control you wanted... you want the taskbar slider?

Comment: @ravery Basically what happens when you press the volume up key on your keyboard. Like what package/program responds to that. `Kmix` does apparently, although it is not the default one.